# jquery menu problem

Tags: jquery, tabs, hover

I have menu with tabs:

```
<div class="section">
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul><!--//topnav-->


<div class="tabbox">
 Tab here
</div>
<div class="tabbox">
 Tab here
</div>
<div class="tabbox">
 Tab here
</div>

</div><!--//section-->
```

And here is jQuery code:

```
  (function($) {  
    $(function() { 
  $('ul.topnav').delegate('li:not(.curtab)', 'click', function(event) {  
      $(this).addClass('curtab').siblings().removeClass('curtab')
     .parents('div.section').find('div.tabbox').hide().eq($(this).index()).show(); });})

   })(jQuery)
```

What I need is to rewrite this menu for hover event, and when you mouseover the `<li>` element, tab appears, if you mouseout - it disappears and also when you mouseout of the `<li>` and goes down to the tab, it should not disappear, currently I tried to make it work, but when I mouseover `<li>` and go down to hover the tab, it disappears

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best way to do it, but what I do is give a delay before closing. Then when it goes to close I test to see if the mouse is over either the opener or the tabbox menu.

Below is an example of a panel menu I am using that is very simplistic.

```
var timer = null;
var timer2 = null;
var buttonHot = false;
var navHot = false;
var menuOpen = false;
var inMotion = false;
var activeMenu = null;
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#adminButton').mouseover(function() {
            buttonHot = true;
            activeMenu = 'adminMenu';
            startOpenTimer();
        }); 
        $('#adminButton').mouseout(function() {
            buttonHot = false;
            startCloseTimer();
        });
        $('#personnelButton').mouseover(function() {
            buttonHot = true;
            activeMenu = 'personnelMenu';
            startOpenTimer();
        }); 
        $('#personnelButton').mouseout(function() {
            buttonHot = false;
            startCloseTimer();
        });

        $('#panelMenu').mouseover(function() {
            navHot = true;
            openMenu();
        }); 
        $('#panelMenu').mouseout(function() {
            navHot = false;
            startCloseTimer();
        });

    }
);

function startCloseTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(closeMenu, 150);
}

function startOpenTimer() {
    timer2 = setTimeout(openMenu, 90);
}

function openMenu() {
    if(buttonHot) {
        $('#adminMenu').hide();
        $('#schoolMenu').hide();
        $('#personnelMenu').hide();
        $('#' + activeMenu).show();

        $('#panelMenu').show();
        if (!menuOpen && !inMotion) {
            inMotion = true;
            $('#panelMenuSlide').slideDown(400, setOpen);
        } else {
            if (inMotion) {
                $('#panelMenuSlide').stop(true, true);
                inMotion = false;
                openMenu()
            }
        }
    }
}

function setOpen() {
    inMotion = false;
    menuOpen = true;
}

function closeMenu() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if (menuOpen && !navHot && !buttonHot) {
        inMotion = true;
        $('#panelMenuSlide').slideUp(400, hideMenu); 
    }
    if (inMotion) {
        startCloseTimer();
    }
}

function hideMenu() {
    menuOpen = false;
    inMotion = false;
    if (!navHot && !buttonHot) {
        $('#panelMenu').hide();
    } else {
        openMenu();
    }
}

function setOpen() {
    menuOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I restructured the HTML to put the tabs inside the `<li>` tags so that hovering over the tab keeps the li trigger on:

```
<div class="section">
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">First</a>
            <div class="tabbox">
                Tab 1
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Second</a>
            <div class="tabbox">
                Tab 2
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Third</a>
            <div class="tabbox">
                Tab 3
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul><!--//topnav-->
</div><!--//section-->
```

And changed the jQuery to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to determine if the tabs should show or hide:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('ul.topnav').delegate('li:not(.curtab)', 'mouseenter', function(e) {
            $(this).addClass('curtab')
                .siblings().removeClass('curtab')
                .parents('div.section').find('div.tabbox').hide()
                .eq($(this).index()).show();
        });
        $('ul.topnav').delegate('li', 'mouseleave', function(e) {
            $(this).removeClass('curtab')
                .parents('div.section').find('div.tabbox').hide();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Tested and functional. http://jsfiddle.net/nAmAh/